# What is the best branching strategy in TFS to share code between multiple team projects?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, release-management

This is a theoretical question about branching, not about code architecture or layers.

I have a Team Project "SuperLibs" with 25 .NET projects (which are class libraries).
Team Project's structure is such:

- Main (current stable version under development)
- Dev (branched from Main - unstable code under development)
- Releases\Release 1.0
- Releases\Release 2.0
- Releases\etc...

And I have another Team Project "SuperLogic", which contains a logic for application and depends only on 5 projects from SuperLibs.
Team Project's structure is such:

- Main (current stable version under development)
- Dev (branched from Main - unstable code under development)
- Shared\SuperLibs\Release 1.0 (branched from Release 1.0 of SuperLibs)
- Shared\SuperLibs\Release 2.0 (branched from Release 2.0 of SuperLibs)
- Releases\Release 1.0
- Releases\Release 2.0
- Releases\etc...

And finally I have third Team Project "SuperApp" which depends both on "SuperLibs" and on "SuperLogic".
Team Project's structure is such:

- Main (current stable version under development)
- Dev (branched from Main - unstable code under development)
- Shared\SuperLibs\Release 1.0 (branched from Release 1.0 of SuperLibs)
- Shared\SuperLibs\Release 2.0 (branched from Release 2.0 of SuperLibs)
- Shared\SuperLogic\Release 1.0 (branched from Release 1.0 of SuperLogic)
- Shared\SuperLogic\Release 2.0 (branched from Release 2.0 of SuperLogic)
- Releases\Release 1.0
- Releases\Release 2.0
- Releases\etc...

No binary references used. Only project references are used.

Now here is the situation:

- When I build "SuperLibs" - everything is ok
- When I build "SuperLogic" - everything is still ok, because SuperLogic is referencing SuperLibs' projects in folder "Shared\SuperLibs\Release x.y"
- But when I try to build "SuperApp" - it fails, because it is able to reference SuperLogic and SuperLibs inside "Shared" folder, but "SuperLogic" in "Shared" folder cannot reference "SuperLibs".

While I have no wish to play around with referenced paths of branched projects, maybe someone has experience with similar projects branching or can offer better branching strategy?

Comment: I use Team Foundation Server 2012.

Comment: Why are they separate team projects? Do you need different security for each? Different process templates? Very different release cadences? It would be a lot easier if you simply had three different trees within the same team project. You could then add the library projects as project references in the solutions which require them.

Comment: It is so for many reasons. Basically I would go for a single Team Project, but since I cannot - I have to solve it with several Team Projects :)

Comment: This looks like a massive anti pattern and completely over engineered. Dependencies should be built and referenced via nuget. even if you could come up with a branching strategy to support what you're trying to do it would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: NuGet is a tool (which by the way fails in many situations and requires manual maintenance). We do not want to depend on tools. So far we were able to do it.
Anyway: do you know of any good pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just remove branching from the equation entirely. You're branching these three things separately, which means you're versioning them separately. If you're versioning them separately, turn everything into NuGet packages and reference the binaries via NuGet.

Comment: Yes, correctly you should not share code used by more than one solution. It's a massive anti pattern that results in poor code quality.